# How would I deal with an enemy that intends to camp underground until I die from the environment as a level 12 fairy wizard?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, targeting, tactics, player-vs-player

This ties in to my previous question, where the answer was that I can't target them with a spell because the ground acts as full cover.

The context for this question is that my enemy (another player) burrowed 5 feet underground after transforming into an earth elemental, and I only had like one AOE spell, that being tidal wave. I can't burrow after them and I can't target them with spells because of full cover, and there's a pillar that attacks the players twice per round, dealing 10 unavoidable DM damage sometimes. No roll to dodge, just take 10 damage regardless of resistances. I don't have any healing spells prepared, and I can't break the ground with a heavy weapon because I'm a fairy, which is small.

Is there a way for me to defeat them in this situation if they decide to not resurface, and just let me die to the pillar, or am I just fated to die?

Comment: Are you really on your own? This sounds like an odd DND scenario

Comment: It was a free for all, so no teams, and one of the other players was able to transform into an earth elemental, which can burrow.

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot.  The Wizard's most powerful ability is "leave and come back later", but you can't do that.  Normally you'd just memorize _move earth_ and maybe _polymorph_ or a spell to make the dirt too hard to burrow through, and maybe toss a pick and shovel in your bag of holding (even a tiny fairy can move dirt), but with none of those options available to you, it sounds to me like you lost the arena fight by failing to prepare, both the highest crime and top cause of death among wizards.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the exact tules of this PvP setup. What counts as a loss? How much time is there? Etc. After all, the Earth Elemental player already fled the arena by burrowing away, so leaving seems to have no penalty?

Comment: We weren't told the situation until we started, including the fact that we weren't told there was an electrical ceiling 80 feet in the air until right after I died, and I  to the 10 points of unavoidable, unblockable DM damage. prior to my death, I was blown into lethal 60 foot high fire by the pillar. When I died, I automatically failed one death save because I fell from 60 feet in the air, and then before my first rolled death save, I automatically failed about one due to the pillar's DM damage. this affectively meant that unless I got a nat 20 first try, I was dead. I rolled a 3.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin there were 4 players, all level 12. You lose if you fail all death saves. The player didn't leave, as they couldn't. Underground is still part of the area, as the pillar sank down into the ground. The pillar was the only source of damage they took while underground. They did eventually resurface, but that was after I died. There wasn't any specified time limit.

Comment: I'm not upset that I rolled badly on my death save, I'm more upset that I died to unavoidable, unblockable damage when I couldn't find any healing spells I could learn as a wizard, and then failed 2 saves before I even got the chance to roll my first save. Sorry if I was ranting

Comment: What were your spells? What your wizards subclass? For example, an abjuration wizards has a way to create a temp hp buffer. Any wizard has ways to create temp hp with false life, but hiding out in a wall of force, or even longer a rope trick would likely be more effective to negate ongoing environmental damage

Comment: I only had access to school of evocation as I did this on DND beyond, and didn't have false life because I didn't think we would have material components. I mostly brought ranged spells, but I did have warding wind and misty step. I didn't bring rope trick because I didn't know what it did and I didn't think we had material components. I built my character around not being hit in the first place, and we weren't told about the pillar that hurts us until we started, so I didn't prepare for unblockable damage ahead of time.

Comment: @Tasi I see. I probably would not have made a wizard if I expected to nor get access to material components, or a spell focus. That is a huge part of your best feature, spellcasting, going right out of the window from the start. Are you aware you can use a focus in place of common (no valuable) components (PH p 203)?

Comment: FYI, Wizards can't normally learn any healing spells.  Even if they take the Magic Initiate feat for Cure Wounds, that doesn't let them cast it using their own spell slots, only once / long rest from the feat.  (Unlike some other feats like Fey Touched that let you use your own spell slots on the spells you get, but limit your choice of schools.)  This is a world-building design decision in D&D: arcane magic learned through book study with no involvement of divine / celestial powers or lineage can't heal, only necromancy stuff like False Life.  Except artificers where it's flavored as alchemy

Comment: I participated in some PvP arenas like this back in the 3.5 era (mostly GM-less), and the winner was usually the person who was most creative, not the one to build the most powerful character(s).  I forget the details, but one event was won by the guy who had a pair of mid-level Koa-toa who flooded the entire arena area and effectively disabled everyone who wasn't aquatic.  Sometimes, by the time you get to the table, it's already too late to have a chance to win.

Comment: Not that it matters now, but the DM could have been generous to the other player, since Earth elemental's earth glide ability is restricted: "The elemental can burrow through nonmagical, unworked earth and stone."  Whilst the description of the arena sounds very much like a *built* location. The elemental's player was lucky that the DM either did not know that rule, or ruled very generously in their favour, since the "winning move" seems in all honesty a quite cheap gotcha given the DM decides answer to questions like "what is the floor made of?" A DM planning a large battle would not do that

Comment: Reminder to everyone that answers, partial answers, suggestions on where to find an answer, frame challenges, and general advice to the asker do not belong in comments.

Comment: Your question does not lend itself to a practical answer. Please list all of the spells that you have prepared, all of your magical items, how many spell slots you have expended, and what cantrips you have.  Also, list all mundane equipment that you have.  You want solutions, list the assets.  then someone can offer you a solution.

Comment: No magical items, and I don't remember the spells because I already deleted the character.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### There is *always* a way

Nobody's answer provides some specifics, this is more general:

You ask:

> Is there a way for me to defeat them in this situation if they decide to not resurface, and just let me die to the pillar, or am I just fated to die?

In the billion permutations open to you, there must be winning combinations.

Without knowing all the parameters, we can't tell you the winning combinations.

#### Leverage your strengths, their weaknesses, and the environment

*What are our liabilities? . . . Our assets?* -- Westly, *The Princess Bride*

We don't know what these are.  You do.  You need to use your strengths, their weaknesses, and the environment to your advantage.  I know that sounds simplistic, but it isn't.

As an example, don't fairy PC's have *enlarge/reduce*?  What could you use it for?  I don't know, but maybe you do.  You mentioned being limited by your small size.  Perhaps *enlarge/reduce* would have helped.

#### Change the game

*Saavik: On the test, sir. Will you tell me what you did? I would really like to know.  Kirk: I changed the conditions of the test. . . . I don't like to lose.*  — *Star Trek: the Wrath of Khan*

They're talking about the Kobayashi Maru, a purposely unwinnable training exercise.

If you think your contest is purposely unwinnable, break the rules.  Try casting *tidal wave* **at the judge**, or something unexpected.

#### Refuse to play

"The only winning move is not to play" - Joshua, in *War Games*

Sometimes you just have to refuse to play.  You might not "win" this apparently unwinnable game, but maybe you'll gain a moral victory.

I am meaning in character, but maybe out of character too.  This is supposed to be fun.  Is it fun?  It doesn't sound like fun.  Maybe a conversation with the DM is warranted.

#### Play another day

"Some days you eat the bear, some days the bear eats you." - *The Big Lebowski*

I don't have a quote for this one, but a great thing about D&D is that while it is a meaningful and exciting game, it is just a game.  You can choose to play your character (or a different one) another day.

Comment: The reason I mentioned being limited by size is because of the lack of capability to use heavy weapons. I therefore didn't bring heavy weapons. There was no judge, just an empty area with an electrical ceiling and 4 players instructed to kill each other. We weren't told the situation we would be dealing with before the game, just that we were level 12. My strengths were being out of melee range and causing ranged attacks to have disadvantage. I don't know the opponent's weaknesses.

Comment: My weaknesses were unavoidable damage and the lack of healing

Comment: If I refused to play, I would just eventually die to the pillar's unavoidable damage. I'm pretty sure I did a grand total of 2 attacks, one of which was to put out the 60 foot high fire that another player set up, everything else was spent running away

Comment: I don't think you can give us enough information to provide a specific answer.  Everything we say, leads you to add another tidbit of detail.  But even if you gave us *everything*, we weren't there, we cannot provide a **specific** answer.  If it were a published module, then sure.  I hope the answers here give you some food for thought, though.  And you know, a 12th level wizard can have a pretty significant spell list.  We can't tell you what you should have taken.

Comment: Oh, and regarding your strengths, surely your wizard spell list was among your assets.

Comment: I mainly had instant spells with a long range that had at most one drop of water for material components, as I didn't know we would have material components. I tried to use warding wind to prevent the pillar from damaging me, but the 10 damage didn't have a save to prevent or reduce the damage.

Comment: You know a component pouch or arcane focus replaces material components that don't have a cost, right?

Comment: Well, now I do.

Comment: Didn't know that before.

Comment: See here.  https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#MaterialM

Comment: @Tasi: This sounds weird to me.  Were all the players and DM new to 5e?  Most people with any experience would know that wizards components aren't supposed to be a struggle, usually just narrative flavour unless your character gets thrown in jail and all their possessions taken.  Wizards can normally cast most of their spells.  And how did you have Guiding Bolt as a wizard?  From the Quandrix Student background from Strixhaven, or a feat like Magic Initiate or Strixhaven Initiate?  It's only on the Cleric spell list for learning / preparing it without special features.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't have guiding bolt, this was just an afterthought

Comment: @Tasi: You could have picked a wizard attack-roll spell like Fire Bolt as your example.  And you didn't answer the part about whether everyone at the table was new to 5e.

Comment: I don't think they're new, as the DM was the sponsor for DND club at school, and the other players have been part of the club for probably all school year so far at least, probably more

Comment: @Tasi "I am meaning in character, but maybe out of character too. This is supposed to be fun. Is it fun? It doesn't sound like fun. Maybe a conversation with the DM is warranted." This is the best advice here. D&D is not meant to be a competitive PVP game. That's not saying it's wrong to do that if everyone is having fun, but it sounds like you didn't have fun. D&D is meant to be a cooperative PVE game.

Comment: Well, at least I had more fun than the time the wind created a lightning storm while I was completely covered head to toe in metal with a premade character and died before I even got a single turn

Comment: @Tasi sounds more like you need a different DM

Comment: Sadly, there is not always a way. This applies in games and in life. Some things are simply impossible. And sometimes even if you do everything right, you can still lose.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman You are right!  Hence my other suggestions.

Answer (score 20):

### Just leave

As a level 12 wizard you have access to spells like *dimension door* and given the size of typical dungeon maps, this should be plenty to get out of there. If, for some reason, you decided to not pick or prepare this staple, there are many other options you could use to improve your situation, from *gaseous form*, to *misty step* in combination with a familiar, to *resilient sphere*, to *knock*, to *rope trick*, to trying to *dispel magi*c the fan effect.  You don't even state there is anything forcing you to stay in the room, so just move away. Nobody is forcing you to win every fight.

If, for some reason, you have opted to not learn or prepare *any* defensive or escape hatch type spells, it is also worth examining all other parameters of the situation you are in. Assuming that your DM has not simply set you up to die for your lack of foresight, there may be other options — to disable the column in some way, to find secret doors, to negotiate for your life. Part of this game is thinking on your feet to creatively solve problems that you can not just power through.

And if this is a PvP setup, as you comment, then neither of you will win if both of you opt to disengage and not reengage.

Comment: I think this is the key lesson here; Don't know the situation? Plan for them all.

Comment: Dimension door would be a perfectly practical way of exercising @Jack's answer of "refuse to play".